# How to integrate admin panel in sails js?

Tags: sails.js

I am new in sails js. I have created front-end in sails js. Now i have to create admin panel in sails. In front-end we have a login and signup functionalities. Then how can i create a admin panel in same server?

Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-adminpanel